# How to implement models of product in relation with order and orderitem

Tags: django, django-models, error-handling, database-migration

I am creating a multivendor ecommerce website in django i want when a person make an order he can add multiple items that belong to multiple vendors so when the order get proceded each vendor will have the items from the order that are specific to him and he can call the person who ordered then (wanna make it simple) am encountering the issue im my modelisation i don't know how to set the model for the order (who should have a list of ordered items each item is linked to the product specific to that item along with the quantity that the person is ordering so the order item class is linked with onetoone relation with product and the order is linked to order item with ontomany relationship

when i create it i get this error :

ERRORS:

Store.OrderItem.product: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Product', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

Store.OrderItem.product: (fields.E307) The field Store.OrderItem.product was declared with a lazy reference to 'Store.product', but app 'Store' doesn't provide model 'product'.

here is my code

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)  # Assuming quantity cannot be negative   
    
class Order(models.Model) : 
     
   name=models.CharField(max_length = 25)  
   address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   phone_nbr = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10 ,default='00000')
   note=models.CharField(max_length = 25,default='No comment ')
   date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, editable=False)
   order = models.ManyToManyField('OrderItem')
   
   
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Set default value for date if not provided
        if not self.date:
            self.date = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   
   def _str_(self) :
       return self.name
   
   



//the product model (in another file am making sure to import it as well
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25,default='Anonymous Product')
    type_p = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    size = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, editable=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User , null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=14 , default="Available")
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Set default value for date if not provided
        if not self.date:
            self.date = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I expect for the migration to happen however i get errors when i try tomigrate my code i've tried different approachs and didn't get to the right one

Answer (score 0):

To prevent referencing issues, you'd want to define the `Product` class before the `OrderItem` class. When `OrderItem` references `Product`, ensuring `Product` is defined first helps avoid errors due to a missing reference. This sequence ensures Django can recognize the `Product` class when `OrderItem` refers to it.